# Attachments extraction using dataloader

Tags: data

I am trying to extract all Attachments from a sandbox using Dataloader(salesforce provided inbuilt application) but I didn't find 'Attachments' object in object selection.

Whereas if I do the same thing using dataloader.io, I am getting 'Attachments' object and able to extract all attachments.

Is there any limitation with  Salesforce Dataloader with Attachments extraction?

Comment: if you want individual files  -- this tool, although old, is handy: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Iz0jEAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the step 2, Select checkbox "Show all Salesforce objects" and you will see all salesforce object and also "Attachment"

Comment: @Sivananda2320 can you accept the answer if this has helped you reach your solution

Comment: @PranayJaiswal :_- accepted